# Defining a static array in a file other than main.cpp

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to have a static array of pokemon species structs, with each index in the array containing the name of each pokemon and its catch rate. I'm trying to declare and define it in a file named SpeciesList.hpp.

```
#ifndef SPECIESLIST_HPP
#define SPECIESLIST_HPP

#include "Species.hpp" // In which the struct species is defined as 
                       // struct species {
                       //     std::string name;
                       //     int catchRate;
                       // };

static species speciesList[719];
speciesList[1].name = "Bulbasaur";
speciesList[1].catchRate = 45;
speciesList[2].name = "Ivysaur";
speciesList[2].catchRate = 45;
// Hundreds of others...

#endif // SPECIESLIST_HPP
```

That code compiles with no trouble when I don't include SpeciesList.hpp into my main.cpp file. Furthermore, it also compiles when I use the aforementioned declaration of the speciesList in my SpeciesList.hpp file, include the SpeciesList.hpp file in my main.cpp file, and define that speciesList in my main.cpp file instead of the SpeciesList.hpp file. However, when I try to use the aforementioned declaration and definitions, I get these errors

```
error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
speciesList[1].name = "Bulbasaur"; // With speciesList underlined.

error: expected ';' after top level declarator
speciesList[1].name = "Bulbasaur"; // With the dot operator being pointed to.

error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
speciesList[1].catchRate = 45; // speciesList underlined again.

error: expected ';' after top level declarator
speciesList[1].catchRate = 45; // Dot operator pointed to again.
```

Question is in the title.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't use expressions like `speciesList[1].name = "Bulbasaur";` in that context. If you'd like to define the entire array at compile time, you can declare it like this:

```
static const species speciesList[] = {
    { "Bulbasaur", 45 },
    // etc.
};
```

Note, however, that this puts Bulbasaur at index 0 of the array.

To improve readability and extensibility, you could define a constructor for your struct, like so:

```
struct species {
    std::string name;
    int catchRate;

    species(const std::string &n, int c)
      : name(n), catchRate(c)
    {
    }
};
```

And then declare your array like:

```
static const species speciesList[] = {
    species("Bulbasaur", 45),
    // etc.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++11 available, you can initialise the array like this:

```
static species speciesList[719] = {
 {"Bulbasaur", 45},
 {"Ivysaur", 45},
 ...
 };
```

Look up uniform initialisation in C++11.

If you can't use this feature, but have access to Boost, you can use the Boost Assign library to do something like this (be warned, I can't check right now, but this is the idea):

```
static species speciesList[719] = boost::assign::array_of<species>
  ("Bulbasaur", 45)
  ("Ivysaur", 45)
  ...;
```